How To Resolve Build Or Run Problem In React Native
I'm currently trying to set up a new React Native project on my machine, but I'm running into some issues during the installation of the React Native SDK. Here are the steps I've taken and the problems I've encountered:
I am Installing Appodeal Plugin For React Native And I  Follow These Steps From docs in the build.gradel
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads:sdk:3.3.0.+'
    ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://artifactory.appodeal.com/appodeal" }
        ...
    }
}

and install NPM package
but during build, I get an error
like this.
is there any way to fix this issue
    (node:18468) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
    (Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
    info JS server already running.
    info Detected architectures arm64-v8a
    info Installing the app...
    
    > Configure project :react-native-reanimated
    Android gradle plugin: 7.3.1
    Gradle: 7.5.1
    WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the gradle.properties file or use the new publishing DSL.
    
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
    
    You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
    
    See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
       > Could not find com.appodeal.ads:sdk:3.3.0.0.
         Required by:
             project :app
    
    * Try:
    > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 13s
    
    error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
    Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeDebugArchitectures=arm64-v8a -PreactNativeArchitectures=arm64-v8a
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
       > Could not find com.appodeal.ads:sdk:3.3.0.0.
         Required by:
             project :app
    
    * Try:
    > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 13s
    
     

Any idea what could it be?
I don't know why this is happening .
